# Apk signed with no rsa or dsa compatible signature

Tags: android-studio

I am building an signed apk to uploaded on a mdm.

I used to do this routine without a problem but since I updated to android studio Arctic Fox 2021.3.1 I get the message:

"Your apk is signed using a certificate that we currently don't support. Please use RSA or DSA certificate".

Aren't apks signed with rsa or dsa certificates?
How can I use these kind of certificates ?

Comment: How do you sign the created APK (jarsigner or apksigner) and which key type has the used signing key?

Comment: I use android studio generate signed bundles with apk.

Comment: Please check the used keystore and the contained private key of which type it is. Th easiest way is to open the keystore file in a  GUI program like https://keystore-explorer.org